# Getting a type error in a recursive flatten method implementation

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching

I am trying to learn scala. Today I am attempting to write a simple recursive method that flattens a nested list. I know that there is a flatten function I could call but I am trying to do it from scratch.

I get a type mismatch error and I am trying to understand why. What type of variable is 'A'.

```
def flatten[A](lst:List[List[A]):List[A] = lst match{

case Nil=> Nil
case (h:List[A])::tail=> flatten(h)::flatten(tail)
case h :: tail=> flatten(tail)
}
```

Comment: If you are interested in a solution for unlimited depth lists check here: https://github.com/izmailoff/scala-s-99/blob/master/src/main/scala/s99/p07/P07.scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatten(h)` is a compiler error because `h` is a `List[A]` but `flatten` is expecting a nested `List[List[A]]`. Try simply concatenating `h` with the result of flattening `tail`:

```
def flatten[A](lst: List[List[A]]): List[A] = lst match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h :: tail => h ::: flatten(tail)
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> flatten(List(List("a", "b"), List("c", "d")))
res0: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d)

scala> flatten(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Great! I am sorry as I am new to scala but what is the function of ':::'?

Comment: It merges two lists. `List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: ok.thanks! This particular exercise in the book uses only pattern matching '::'. If I were to use that would I just call and pattern match two heads and tails?